# SVG Image Masking on Firefox

Tags: svg, mask, masking

recently I create hexagon SVG, and I plan to implement it for image masking for firefox.
currently its only working for Chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/brokeneye/WKEbw/

I already try to use `mask: url` but it seems doesn't work.

Solved

Found the solution for this, its working on Firefox, chrome, safari, opera and IE9. Need to define the img on the SVG. the sample code is on this fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/brokeneye/ygsKm/

Answer (score 0):

Firefox supports what you want to do in a different way. You can use [SVG masks with html images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example%3a.C2.A0Masking) to get the same effect there with a different syntax.

Comment: I see that, so probably I need to change everything to make it working on all browser.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single solution that would work everywhere yet. You do one thing for webkit and another for gecko, I imagine at some point a single solution will emerge but I'm not sure which one will be the winner.

Comment: Found the solution for this, its working on Firefox, chrome, safari, opera and IE9. Need to define the img on the SVG. the sample code is on this fiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/brokeneye/ygsKm/