# html svg animation doesnt work on firefox (working on chrome)

Tags: html, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I found this svg animation example:
http://codepen.io/hbuchel/pen/qLxAB?editors=110
it is working on chrome, but not working on firefox..
I can only see the image without animation.. I don't understand why..

How can I make it working on firefox?

**Update:** Before I supposed to be the `css` animation the problem, but I tested it and works fine, so is another problem..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `-webkit-animation` and others?

```
.clip {
  -webkit-animation: slide 8s infinite; 
  -moz-animation: slide 8s infinite;
  -o-animation: slide 8s infinite;
  animation: slide 8s infinite;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WsWWY/1/ I'm taking a look at this now. (which comes from this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844520/css-animation-works-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox) If this works in my firefox browser then there's got to be something little that needs to be altered.

Comment: I think firefox does support what you want to do but only in a different way after looking at this page in chrome and firefox seperately.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content#Example%3a.C2.A0Masking. I also found a similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698719/svg-image-masking-on-firefox which might help you somewhat more.